# python - parsing and sorting dates

Tags: python, sorting, date, datetime

I have an HTML file that is composed of 10 megs of the following:

```
<span class="user">Chat User1</span>
<span class="meta">Friday, August 29, 2014 at 6:03pm PDT</span>
<p>Some text</p>

<span class="user">Chat User2</span>
<span class="meta">Friday, August 29, 2014 at 6:01pm PDT</span>
<p>Some preceding text</p>
```

The dates are kind of all over the place in the file, and, for each date, the chats for a given session are in reverse order.

What I'd like to do is to to be able to, in python, is to construct a text file that writes everything out in chronological order, i.e.:

```
Chat User 2
Friday, August 29, 2014 at 6:01pm PDT
Some preceding text

Chat User 1
Friday, August 29, 2014 at 6:02pm PDT
Some text

...
```

I'm not sure what the best approach is here, given the size of the file, but I was thinking about... maybe building up a large dict that has a `user`, `date`, and `text` keys (with string, datetime, string as respective data types)  and then sorting that on `date`? Honestly not sure what the best approach to this might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For just 10 megs, I will definitly go with a in memory sort. I would parse the HTML with [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), create a array of object with the given class :

```
class Chat:
    def __init__(self, user, date, text):
        self.user = user
        self.date = date
        self.text = text
```

And sort the array with :

```
ut.sort(key=lambda x: x.date, reverse=True)
```

But if the order is perfect reverse in the original file and you do not want to use a lot of memory, you could read the file chat by chat and insert each chat at the beginning of your result file.